# Can there be too many answers to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes there are many answers to a single question, for example [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311108/test-method-is-inconclusive-test-wasnt-run-error), with 60+ answers. I find it to be too many.

Is there a procedure to maybe close such questions, or something? It would be nice if it just had one answer that told you how to find the real answer (clicking the "output" button in the above example) Then the real errors could be searched for as separate questions.

Anyway, is this grounds for closing the question? Is there a way to mark the "find your specific real problem" answer out of the 60+ to show up first or be linked to?

Comment: There is a *wiki answer lock* feature that can be used as by a moderator to restrict further answers while still keeping the question open and its answers open to edits. You'd need to request this on the per-site meta, Meta Stack Overflow, as here we deal with general situations as they apply to all sites; this question's situation is with regards to just one site.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if there was a general stack-way to approach the problem. The question gave me nightmares of being back on a forum! #neveragain. Sounds like the "general way" might be to just post it on that sub-domains meta page? I'll get on it, then!

Comment: The linked question is specific to a particular site and should be posted on the site's meta instead and closed. I found that it has already been cross-posted to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385002/question-has-too-many-answers

Comment: I've made a major edit and voted to reopen, it's a valid discussion about the usefulness of many answers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Too Broad is often applicable for questions with a *very* broad range of different answers.  In some cases (I'm not sufficiently familiar with the topic to comment on your example) the issue may be that the question is lacking sufficient clarifying information to actually know what the problem is, causing people to post lots of different guesses, so while such a question meets the criteria for Too Broad, the root cause of why it's too broad would be because it's Unclear.

Questions can also be protected if they're attracting large numbers of low quality answers, to add some barriers in place to people posting an answer.  This has in fact already recently happened for that post.